# Memory leaks when using pandas_udf and Parquet serialization?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyarrow

I am currently developing my first whole system using PySpark and I am running into some strange, memory-related issues. In one of the stages, I would like to resemble a Split-Apply-Combine strategy in order to modify a DataFrame. That is, I would like to apply a function to each of the groups defined by a given column and finally combine them all. Problem is, the function I want to apply is a prediction method for a fitted model that "speaks" the Pandas idiom, i.e., it is vectorized and takes a Pandas Series as an input.

I have then designed an iterative strategy, traversing the groups and manually applying a pandas_udf.Scalar in order to solve the problem. The combination part is done using incremental calls to DataFrame.unionByName(). I have decided not to use the GroupedMap type of pandas_udf because the docs state that the memory should be managed by the user, and you should have special care whenever one of the groups might be too large to keep it in memory or be represented by a Pandas DataFrame.

The main problem is that all the processing seems to run fine, but in the end I want to serialize the final DataFrame to a Parquet file. And it is at this point where I receive a lot of Java-like errors about DataFrameWriter, or out-of-memory exceptions.

I have tried the code in both Windows and Linux machines. The only way I have managed to avoid the errors has been to increase the --driver-memory value in the machines. The minimum value is different in every platform, and is dependent on the size of the problem, which somehow makes me suspect on memory leaks.

The problem did not happen until I started using pandas_udf. I think that there is probably a memory leak somewhere in the whole process of pyarrow serialization taking place under the hood when using a pandas_udf.

I have created a minimal reproducible example. If I run this script directly using Python, it produces the error. Using spark-submit and increasing a lot the driver memory, it is possible to make it work.

```py
import pyspark
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as spktyp


# Dummy pandas_udf -------------------------------------------------------------
@F.pandas_udf(spktyp.DoubleType())
def predict(x):
    return x + 100.0


# Initialization ---------------------------------------------------------------
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName(
        "mre").master("local[3]").getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext

# Generate a dataframe ---------------------------------------------------------
out_path = "out.parquet"

z = 105
m = 750000

schema = spktyp.StructType(
    [spktyp.StructField("ID", spktyp.DoubleType(), True)]
)

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(float(i),) for i in range(m)],
    schema
)

for j in range(z):
    df = df.withColumn(
        f"N{j}",
        F.col("ID") + float(j)
    )

df = df.withColumn(
    "X",
    F.array(
        F.lit("A"),
        F.lit("B"),
        F.lit("C"),
        F.lit("D"),
        F.lit("E")
    ).getItem(
        (F.rand()*3).cast("int")
    )
)

# Set the column names for grouping, input and output --------------------------
group_col = "X"
in_col = "N0"
out_col = "EP"

# Extract different group ids in grouping variable -----------------------------
rows = df.select(group_col).distinct().collect()
groups = [row[group_col] for row in rows]
print(f"Groups: {groups}")

# Split and treat the first id -------------------------------------------------
first, *others = groups

cur_df = df.filter(F.col(group_col) == first)
result = cur_df.withColumn(
    out_col,
    predict(in_col)
)

# Traverse the remaining group ids ---------------------------------------------
for i, other in enumerate(others):
    cur_df = df.filter(F.col(group_col) == other)
    new_df = cur_df.withColumn(
        out_col,
        predict(in_col)
    )

    # Incremental union --------------------------------------------------------
    result = result.unionByName(new_df)

# Save to disk -----------------------------------------------------------------
result.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(out_path)
```

Shockingly (at least for me), the problem seems to vanish if I put a call to repartition() just before the serialization statement.

```py
result = result.repartition(result.rdd.getNumPartitions())
result.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(out_path)
```

Having put this line into place, I can lower a lot the driver memory configuration, and the script runs fine. I can barely understand the relationship among all those factors, although I suspect lazy evaluation of the code and pyarrow serialization might be related.

This is the current environment I am using for development:

```
arrow-cpp                 0.13.0           py36hee3af98_1    conda-forge
asn1crypto                0.24.0                py36_1003    conda-forge
astroid                   2.2.5                    py36_0
atomicwrites              1.3.0                      py_0    conda-forge
attrs                     19.1.0                     py_0    conda-forge
blas                      1.0                         mkl
boost-cpp                 1.68.0            h6a4c333_1000    conda-forge
brotli                    1.0.7             he025d50_1000    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2019.3.9             hecc5488_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2019.3.9                 py36_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.12.3           py36hb32ad35_0    conda-forge
chardet                   3.0.4                 py36_1003    conda-forge
colorama                  0.4.1                    py36_0
cryptography              2.6.1            py36hb32ad35_0    conda-forge
dill                      0.2.9                    py36_0
docopt                    0.6.2                    py36_0
entrypoints               0.3                      py36_0
falcon                    1.4.1.post1     py36hfa6e2cd_1000    conda-forge
fastavro                  0.21.21          py36hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
flake8                    3.7.7                    py36_0
future                    0.17.1                py36_1000    conda-forge
gflags                    2.2.2                ha925a31_0
glog                      0.3.5                h6538335_1
hug                       2.5.2            py36hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
idna                      2.8                   py36_1000    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2019.3                      203
isort                     4.3.17                   py36_0
lazy-object-proxy         1.3.1            py36hfa6e2cd_2
libboost                  1.67.0               hd9e427e_4
libprotobuf               3.7.1                h1a1b453_0    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h2fa13f4_0
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py36_1
mkl                       2018.0.3                      1
mkl_fft                   1.0.6            py36hdbbee80_0
mkl_random                1.0.1            py36h77b88f5_1
more-itertools            4.3.0                 py36_1000    conda-forge
ninabrlong                0.1.0                     dev_0    <develop>
nose                      1.3.7                 py36_1002    conda-forge
nose-exclude              0.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.15.0           py36h9fa60d3_0
numpy-base                1.15.0           py36h4a99626_0
openssl                   1.1.1b               hfa6e2cd_2    conda-forge
pandas                    0.23.3           py36h830ac7b_0
parquet-cpp               1.5.1                         2    conda-forge
pip                       19.0.3                   py36_0
pluggy                    0.11.0                     py_0    conda-forge
progressbar2              3.38.0                     py_1    conda-forge
py                        1.8.0                      py_0    conda-forge
py4j                      0.10.7                   py36_0
pyarrow                   0.13.0           py36h8c67754_0    conda-forge
pycodestyle               2.5.0                    py36_0
pycparser                 2.19                     py36_1    conda-forge
pyflakes                  2.1.1                    py36_0
pygam                     0.8.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pylint                    2.3.1                    py36_0
pyopenssl                 19.0.0                   py36_0    conda-forge
pyreadline                2.1                      py36_1
pysocks                   1.6.8                 py36_1002    conda-forge
pyspark                   2.4.1                      py_0
pytest                    4.5.0                    py36_0    conda-forge
pytest-runner             4.4                        py_0    conda-forge
python                    3.6.6                hea74fb7_0
python-dateutil           2.8.0                    py36_0
python-hdfs               2.3.1                      py_0    conda-forge
python-mimeparse          1.6.0                      py_1    conda-forge
python-utils              2.3.0                      py_1    conda-forge
pytz                      2019.1                     py_0
re2                       2019.04.01       vc14h6538335_0  [vc14]  conda-forge
requests                  2.21.0                py36_1000    conda-forge
requests-kerberos         0.12.0                   py36_0
scikit-learn              0.20.1           py36hb854c30_0
scipy                     1.1.0            py36hc28095f_0
setuptools                41.0.0                   py36_0
six                       1.12.0                   py36_0
snappy                    1.1.7                h777316e_3
sqlite                    3.28.0               he774522_0
thrift-cpp                0.12.0            h59828bf_1002    conda-forge
typed-ast                 1.3.1            py36he774522_0
urllib3                   1.24.2                   py36_0    conda-forge
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.15.26706          h3a45250_0
wcwidth                   0.1.7                      py_1    conda-forge
wheel                     0.33.1                   py36_0
win_inet_pton             1.1.0                    py36_0    conda-forge
wincertstore              0.2              py36h7fe50ca_0
winkerberos               0.7.0                    py36_1
wrapt                     1.11.1           py36he774522_0
xz                        5.2.4                h2fa13f4_4
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_3
zstd                      1.3.3                hfe6a214_0
```

Any hint or help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you repartition right after initializing your dataframe and see? Also can you give data sizze and the memory configurations where it is failing/passing. This would certainly help

Comment: Hi. Thank you for commenting. I have tried to repartition at the beginning, just after reading the data from the Parquet file, and it does not work. My guess is that repartition seems to fix something that is broken during the udf stage. About data sizes, seems to be related to the machine you are running the example on. It is easier to make it break (when not using repartition) under my Windows laptop 8GB RAM than in the Ubuntu VM I am using as testing environment. I'll give it a try to come with some numbers and edit the question appropiately if possible. Thanks.

Comment: @Fernandez I am running into a similar issue and was wondering if you found any resolution to this. I tried repartitioning the df before writing it to parquet, but that does not help like it did in your case.

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to comment to your post, but my reputation is too low.

According to my experience udf slow down your performance drastically, especially if you write them in python (or pandas?). There is an article, why you shoudn't use python udfs and use scala udfs instead: https://medium.com/wbaa/using-scala-udfs-in-pyspark-b70033dd69b9

In my case it was possible to use built-in functions, even it was pretty complicated, and the runtime decreased to about 5% compared to before.

For your OOM Error and why a repartition worked for you, I have no explanation. The only advice I can give you is to avoid UDFs as much as possible, although it seems to be not that easy in your case.

Comment: The article is very interesting. Thank you. Problem is, what I am trying to use here is a pandas_udf, not a normal UDF. And we need it because we want to take advantage of the vectorized predict() method of a sklearn-like model. Using UDFs will imply that we would have to call the model once per observation, and I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

This thread is a bit old, but I stumped across the exact same problem and spent quite a few hours ont it. So I just wanted to explain how I solve it, with the hope that it saves some hours for anyone else hitting the same issue in the future.

The problem here is not related to `pandas_udf` or parquet, but with the use of `withColumn` to generate the columns. When adding multiple columns to a dataframe is way more efficient to use the `select` method. [This article](https://medium.com/@manuzhang/the-hidden-cost-of-spark-withcolumn-8ffea517c015) explains why.

So for example, instead of

```
for j in range(z):
   df = df.withColumn(
       f"N{j}",
       F.col("ID") + float(j)
   )
```

you should write

```
df = df.select(
    *df.columns,
    *[(F.col("ID") + float(j)).alias(f"N{j}") for j in range(z)]
)
```

The rewritten script looks like this (Note that I still had to increment the driver memory to 2GB, but at least is quite a reasonable amount of memory)

```
import pyspark
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as spktyp


# Dummy pandas_udf -------------------------------------------------------------
@F.pandas_udf(spktyp.DoubleType())
def predict(x):
    return x + 100.0


# Initialization ---------------------------------------------------------------
spark = (pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder
        .appName("mre")
        .config("spark.driver.memory", "2g")
        .master("local[3]").getOrCreate())

sc = spark.sparkContext

# Generate a dataframe ---------------------------------------------------------
out_path = "out.parquet"

z = 105
m = 750000

schema = spktyp.StructType(
    [spktyp.StructField("ID", spktyp.DoubleType(), True)]
)

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(float(i),) for i in range(m)],
    schema
)


df = df.select(
    *df.columns,
    *[(F.col("ID") + float(j)).alias(f"N{j}") for j in range(z)]
)

df = df.withColumn(
    "X",
    F.array(
        F.lit("A"),
        F.lit("B"),
        F.lit("C"),
        F.lit("D"),
        F.lit("E")
    ).getItem(
        (F.rand()*3).cast("int")
    )
)

# Set the column names for grouping, input and output --------------------------
group_col = "X"
in_col = "N0"
out_col = "EP"

# Extract different group ids in grouping variable -----------------------------
rows = df.select(group_col).distinct().collect()
groups = [row[group_col] for row in rows]
print(f"Groups: {groups}")

# Split and treat the first id -------------------------------------------------
first, *others = groups

cur_df = df.filter(F.col(group_col) == first)
result = cur_df.withColumn(
    out_col,
    predict(in_col)
)

# Traverse the remaining group ids ---------------------------------------------
for i, other in enumerate(others):
    cur_df = df.filter(F.col(group_col) == other)
    new_df = cur_df.select(
        *cur_df.columns,
        predict(in_col).alias(out_col)
    )
    # Incremental union --------------------------------------------------------
    result = result.unionByName(new_df)

# Save to disk -----------------------------------------------------------------
result.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(out_path)
```

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. In my case though there is only one column that I am adding with 'withColumn' so using select is not helping in my case. Any other clues that might have helped you? Thanks!